# Let's get critical: Oct 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [German Language & Usage Stack Exchange](http://german.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://german.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Why do German speakers often use 'did' in the past when speaking English?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7718/why-do-german-speakers-often-use-did-in-the-past-when-speaking-english)

  **Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Wie liest man das Zeichen „§“ vor?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7535/wie-liest-man-das-zeichen-vor)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)
- [Servus mitanand?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7590/servus-mitanand)

  **Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Which of these two is the correct translation for "Silly me"?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7597/which-of-these-two-is-the-correct-translation-for-silly-me)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is this sentence a run-on sentence?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7600/is-this-sentence-a-run-on-sentence)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [How to say “the start of my new life”?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7685/how-to-say-the-start-of-my-new-life)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [When to use "sein" and "haben" for verbs that allow both auxiliary verbs?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7726/when-to-use-sein-and-haben-for-verbs-that-allow-both-auxiliary-verbs)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Classic German Literature](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7643/classic-german-literature)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Weshalb spricht man vom "abgesicherten Modus" und nicht vom "sicheren Modus" in der EDV?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7664/weshalb-spricht-man-vom-abgesicherten-modus-und-nicht-vom-sicheren-modus-in)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Genitiv von Fallnamen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7693/genitiv-von-fallnamen)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)